# Rhythmbox hangs when changing song properties

Tags: rhythmbox, fstab

I am having problems when trying to change song properties in rhythmbox 2.98 (Ubuntu 13.04). I just choose one song, click on properties and do some changes and press close. Now everything seems fine, but it is not. Trying to open properties one more time hangs rhythmbox - it becomes unresponsive for a long tome, but changes really occur, if I wait long enough, additionally `timeout was reached` error has been shown.
I think problem might be in where I have saved songs, because when I copy the song to home folder which is on the same partition as whole system, then editing goes fine.

About songs: they are saved on another ext4 partition and it is mounted on start-up by fstab. I am not sure if it is correct. fstab record here:

```
UUID=3265c492-8ff6-4421-830e-91508d27a020 /mnt/home ext4 auto,user,rw,sync,exec 0 2
```

Hope someone can help me, because I don`t know where else to go.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Okay, I found out what was the problem. 
It was my fstab record, just changed to

```
UUID=3265c492-8ff6-4421-830e-91508d27a020 /mnt/home ext4 defaults,user 0 2
```

and now everything is fine. Problem was sync option that made that partition awfully slow, so slow, that none of the programs could work normally, also thunderbird.